# Integrate multiple unity games in native android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a native android app and I want to embed multiple unity games in this.
I followed [link](https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a) to embed one unity game to the native android app

I would like to embed multiple games. How can I do this?

Comment: Yeah, I've got the same issue. Could compile 2 AARs into a single launcher, even compile it, but only one game is starting whatever I do.

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solution to achieve this?